# Script analysing DIV height non function

Tags: jquery, html, height, expand

I have the following script that is not appearing to work.

```
var height = $('#sidebar1').height();
var pageHeight = $(window).height();

if ((height) > 600) {
  alert('haha');
}
```

The ineveitable conlcusion to this script is to have it analayse against pageHeight rather than 600, but I cannot get this to work even with 600.

I can only conclude it is something to do with this `div: #sidebar1` being a floaty stick element. Here is its CSS.

```
.sidebar { float: right; width: 190px; padding-top:8px; }
```

The script is part of a load whereby the `div: #sidebar1` 's height expands as content is loaded in based on choices in a form.

Any Ideas,

Marvellous

EDIT : 
From including the alert as the height of the element we can see now that the height gets stuck at '430' even though it seemingly continues to expand.
Any ideas

Comment: can we see the html markup too please

Comment: also why don't you alert the height before you compare it to see if you are comparing what you think you are

Comment: try alerting height and see what it has in it.

Comment: From alerting the height we can see that the height gets stuck at '430' even though it appears to continue expanding

Comment: check on fire bug there is a computed height, etc... or inspect Elements DOM to find the actual height of the `#sidebar1`

Comment: Lets see some demo markup and ALL relevant CSS / JS

Comment: http://www.divethegap.com/update/configure/adventure-training?qualification=Beginner&level=1

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following which works for me. Check the 
`id` and `class` attributes for the div element, and make sure the content is actually greater than 600 (height) you can try adding an else statement to see your height:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var height = $('#sidebar1').height();
var pageHeight = $(window).height();

    if ((height) > 600) {
        alert('haha');
    }

    else {
        alert(height);
    }
});


.sidebar { 
    float: right; 
    width: 190px; 
    padding-top:8px; 
}


<div id="sidebar1" class="sidebar">
    <img src="SomeContent.png" width="190" height="601" />
</div>
```