# Changing DIV height return the new value

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html, height

I am trying to get the height of a div.

```
var height = $('#sidebar1').height();
```

The problem is that the height fluctuates depending on what gets loaded into it. The returned result does not. It stays the same. I want it to give me the new height of element. The element however does not have a height. It is simply the height of the block of its element that it contains.

In this case even when the element is more that 600px in height, it still returns it's initial height of '320'

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script analysing DIV height non function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473521/script-analysing-div-height-non-function)

Comment: This is the same question you asked just a short while ago.

Comment: We have determined the cause of the problem thus we're asking a new question based on what the actual problem is

Comment: How do you **know** that the height of the `<div>` is changing?  Have you styled it with a border, or done something even simpler like look at its dimensions with FireBug or some other developer tool?

Comment: Maybe a daft question, but are you querying the height of the div AFTER you've loaded content into it?

Comment: @pointy, correct the DIV is not resizing, I put the border on it. Any idea why.

Comment: Have you tried adding "overflow: hidden" to the sidebar CSS?

Answer (score 1):

This call send show the initial height. but to get height in runtime you need to get height after each load of content within it. make a function for calculate the height after each data load.e.g

```
function he (t){
   $(t).height();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with abdullah.abcoder.

By putting js code in

`<script>$('div id').height()</script>`

you'll only have it run once when the page is loading (and only the html document before this  is loaded).

If you want to calculate the actually height of the div after pages loaded, try

```
<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        $("your div id").height(); // or $().css('height');
    });
</script>
```

To dynamically get the div's height, you need to put it into some events handler function, like div's resizable or draggable.